# How to fix "server access error" when installing Apache Spark 1.5.2 (404 not found)

Tags: apache-spark

I've tried to install Apache Spark 1.5.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 with these steps:

```
wget http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-1.5.2.tgz
tar xvf spark-1.5.2.tgz
cd spark-1.5.2/
./sbt/sbt assembly
```

But I get this build error:

```
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/orgspark-project-1113/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server/2.2.0/hadoop-yarn-server-2.2.0.jar
```

And when I try to open the [url](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/orgspark-project-1113/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server/2.2.0/hadoop-yarn-server-2.2.0.jar) mentioned it gives a 404 not found error. How do I fix this to correctly install Apache Spark 1.5.2?